# Encrypting Cocoa Resources with Custom Build Shell Script

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, sh

I am encrypting some resources in my Cocoa app using the following script ([Source](http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/)):

```
DIRNAME=EncryptedResources
ENC_KEY="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456"

INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$DIRNAME
OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/$DIRNAME

if [ ! -d "$OUTDIR" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"
fi

for file in "$INDIR"/*
do
  echo "Encrypting $file"
  "$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" -e -k $ENC_KEY -i "$file" -o "$OUTDIR/`basename "$file"`"
done
```

However the script doesn't handle sub-directories within the EncryptedResources directory.  I have several nested sub-directories so what would be the easiest way to modify the shell script to handle the sub-directories and have those output correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `find` command instead of your `for` loop.

```
find $INDIR -exec "$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" 
    -e -k $ENC_KEY -i {} -o "$OUTDIR/`basename {}`" \; # all on one line
```

might be a good approximation of what you need to do, but `find` is very hard to use, and I'm working from memory.

Comment: Thanks! I used this as a starting point.  I ended up running find $INDIR -type f and placing the result in an array and then modifying some paths etc.

Comment: @Luke can you explain how you got this? I also faced the same problem.

Comment: @NewStack Sorry about the slow reply.  See my answer on what I ended up using.

Comment: @Luke thank you for your answer. I have another problem when my directory contain space its shows error.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I used the following:

```
DIRNAME=ENCRYPTEDCONTENT
ENC_KEY="INSERT ENCRYPTION KEY HERE"

INDIR=$PROJECT_DIR/$DIRNAME
OUTDIR=$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/Resources/$DIRNAME

if [ ! -d "$OUTDIR" ]; then
mkdir -p "$OUTDIR"
fi


while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' dir;
do
DIRECTORY=`echo $dir | sed -e "s,$INDIR,$OUTDIR,g"`
mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY"
done < <(find "$INDIR" -type d -print0)

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file;
do
OUTFILE=`echo $file | sed -e "s,$INDIR,$OUTDIR,g"`
if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then
echo "Encrypting $file"
"$PROJECT_DIR/crypt" -e -k $ENC_KEY -i "$file" -o "$OUTFILE"
fi
done < <(find "$INDIR" -type f -print0)
```

Comment: I get this error when I run this script - crypt: Key must be 32 bytes